# Update Fields Supplier Invoice

Tags: s4sdk

I'm looking for an Odata service that can update values of supplier invoices. I know that I can do it using BAPI, but I would like to know if there is a way to do it using a update from OData service or something similar.
The fields that I want to change are:

- Block a Payment
- Change Assignment Number
- Change Payee

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now it is not possible to change fields of a supplier invoice. Looking at the [API Hub](https://api.sap.com/api/API_SUPPLIERINVOICE_PROCESS_SRV/resource) you just have the option to create and read supplier invoices as well as releasing/canceling them.

To request a change in the API you can submit a request in the [Customer Influence Site](https://influence.sap.com/sap/ino/#/campaign/1175).